# Supported implicit variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The GNU Makefile has [a documentation page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) which lists standard implicit variables for various compilation contexts, such as `CC`, `CFLAGS`, etc. They are well defined, and pretty safe to employ (I use them all the time).

Looking though extended documentation, beyond the GNU website, I regularly see other variables which are *not* listed on the GNU documentation, such as `COMPILER.c`, `LINK.o`, etc.
Such variables are present in multiple recipes when looking over Github or Internet, and frequently from authors which seem to have a pretty good understanding regarding how `make` works.

The question is:
How reliable is it to use such variables?
They are not documented on the GNU make documentation website, but they seem stable enough that several authors have decided to rely on them. Is it a sane thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that they [*are* documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and are pretty safe to use with GNU *make* (they are not in POSIX *make*).

> However, the recipes in built-in implicit rules actually use variables such as `COMPILE.c`, `LINK.p`, and `PREPROCESS.S`, whose values contain the recipes listed above.
>
> make follows the convention that the rule to compile a `.x` source file uses the variable `COMPILE.x`. Similarly, the rule to produce an executable from a `.x` file uses `LINK.x`; and the rule to preprocess a `.x` file uses `PREPROCESS.x`.